# Command line Tools for Code Blocks

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to install the command line tools on Code::Blocks on my Mac, i have downloaded Xcode and tried to install their command line tools, but i get this error when I try to enter Apple's download page:

[image]

I've even tried downloading from code block preferences , but i don't get the option to:

[image]

Any Suggestions?

My main aim is just to have a C++ compiler working on my Mac, and I'm aiming to start developing C++ applications. Any further suggestions on this alternatively to Code::Blocks would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download xcode and install their command line tools. All of the xcode tools are generally updated well and easy to install

Comment: goto preferences and downloads, it should be there

Comment: where shall i go to prefrences?

Comment: From the menu bar, choose Xcode > Preferences.  In the Preferences window, choose the Downloads icons.  In the Downloads section, choose the Components tab.  Click the Install button at the right end of the row that says Command Line Tools.